# Who are the Diogenes and Zeno Dante encounters in Limbo?

Tags: dante, inferno, divine-comedy

In Limbo Dante encounters a group of philosophers:

> When I had raised my eyes a little higher,
>   I saw the master of the men who know
>   seated in philosophic family.
>
> There all look up to him, all do him honor:
>   there I beheld both Socrates and Plato,
>   closest to him, in front of all the rest;
>
> Democritus, who ascribes the world to chance,
>   Diogenes, Empedocles, and Zeno,
>   and Thales, Anaxagoras, Heraclitus;
>
> I saw the good collector of medicinals,
>   I mean Dioscorides; and I saw Orpheus,
>   and Tully, Linus, moral Seneca;
>
> and Euclid the geometer, and Ptolemy,
>   Hippocrates and Galen, Avicenna,
>   Averroes, of the great Commentary.

*Mandelbaum translation.*

Is this Diogenes [Diogenes the Cynic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes) (the one that lived in a jar) or [Diogenes of Apollonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes_of_Apollonia)? And is Zeno the pre-Socratic philosopher [Zeno of Elea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_of_Elea) or the Stoic [Zeno of Citium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_of_Citium)?

Comment: All of the philosophers in that paragraph are pre-Socratic (assuming Zeno is the Eleatic and not the Stoic), which would imply Diogenes of Apollonia. But since the next paragraph mixes Hellenistic authors with mythological characters, I'm not sure this is a conclusive answer

Comment: @ba Thanks. Since identifying Zeno might help identifying Diogenes, I updated the question to also ask about Zeno.